# Every quotient of a reflexive space is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

How do you prove the following?

> If $\mathcal{X}$ is reflexive and $M \leq \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}/M$ is reflexive

There is no assumption that $\mathcal{X}$ is a Banach space.

Comment: $M$ isn't deemed closed here, is it?

Comment: Note that a reflexive normed space must be a Banach space: since the dual space of a normed space is always complete we have that $\mathcal{X}^{\ast\ast}$ is complete and as the canonical inclusion $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}^{\ast\ast}$ is an isometric isomorphism, it follows that $\mathcal{X}$ is complete. @julien: $X/M$ is always a topological vector space. It might just fail to be Hausdorff.

Comment: @Martin You'r right. I thought we always asked that a topological vector space be Hausdorff... But no.

Comment: @julien: You might still be remembering right. There are many authors who do require topological vector spaces to be Hausdorff (or equivalently  $T_0$ or $T_1$), for example Rudin's *Functional analysis*. I think it's an unfortunate practice even if 99% of the interesting spaces are Hausdorff. Somewhat similar to the situation with compactness, but this time the French are innocent :-)

Answer (score 3):

X is reflexive implies it is Banach and, as M is closed in X, so is X/M. Since duals are Banach always, $X^*$ and $(X/M)^*$ are Banach, which is a closed subspace of the dual of X. Now dual of X is reflexive and hence its closed subspaces are also reflexive. Infact, the quotient is reflexive.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal X$ reflexive, so every functional on $\mathcal X^*$ is an evaluation map. Now consider a functional $g$ on $(\mathcal X/M)^*$. One identifies $(\mathcal X/M)^*$ with the functionals on $\mathcal X$ that vanish on $M$. Now, extend $g$ to all of $\mathcal X^*$ by declaring it $0$ outside of $(\mathcal X/M)^*$. Now we get $x\in\mathcal X$ such that $g$ is the map $f\mapsto f(x)$

Then, restrict $g$ to just the functionals that vanish on $M$.

This gives rise to the realisation of $g$ as an evaluation map.

Since $g$ was arbitrary. We're done $\square$

Comment: I think that extending $g$ to all of $\mathcal{X}^*$ by declaring it  $0$ outside of $(\mathcal{X}/M)^*$ is not right. is it? I think it has to be extended by Hahn-Banach theorem for locally convex spaces. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @Martin: Dear Martin, This describes how $(\mathcal X/M)^*$ sits inside $\mathcal X^*$.  But the issue is how to extend a functional on the former to a functional on the latter.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Dear Matt, Thank you for the correction and clarification. I deleted my comment since it was useless and potentially misleading. Regards,